# How to plot from a scatter object on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I got a scatter object and want to view it but haven't found the right function to do it. I only know that it has following properties:

```
         Marker: 'o'
MarkerEdgeColor: 'none'
MarkerFaceColor: [0.6350 0.0780 0.1840]
       SizeData: 36
      LineWidth: 0.5000
          XData: [1×482 double]
          YData: [1×482 double]
          ZData: [1×0 double]
          CData: [0.6350 0.0780 0.1840]
```

So how can I retrieve the image of this object?
I know view() is for clustergram. But what function is for scatter object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's `scatter` does not support an object as input:

> ```
> scatter(X,Y) draws the markers in the default size and color.
> scatter(X,Y,S) draws the markers at the specified sizes (S) with a single color. This type of graph is also known as a bubble plot.
> scatter(...,M) uses the marker M instead of 'o'.
> scatter(...,'filled') fills the markers.
>
> scatter(AX,...) plots into AX instead of GCA.
>
> H = scatter(...) returns handles to the scatter objects created.
> ```

If you have an scatter object, you can plot it manually or reassign the parent property:

```matlab
o = scatter(rand(20,1),rand(20,1),12,lines(20),'*');
class(o) % it's 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Scatter'

% manually plot the object
figure
scatter(o.XData,o.YData,o.SizeData,o.CData,o.Marker,'LineWidth',o.LineWidth)

% or reassign the parent property
figure
h = axes();
set(o,'Parent',h); % assign o's new parent.
```

Comment: Why didn't Matlab design a function to directly plot out the scatter object?

Comment: No idea. Maybe it's not that common to save the object instead of the raw data and having a script or function to reproduce the plot.